# Bluetooth on Android : how to check whether specific MAC addressed device is still there around me?

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth

Here is my code, reading mac address(that i already stored)
 one by one from the file. Next I want to check whether the device is still there around me. 
can somebody help me.

```
private void search(){
                        String collected;
                       fis=openFileInput(FILENAME);
            byte[] dataArray= new byte[fis.available()];
            while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){

                          collected = new String(dataArray);
                               // here i want to write that code...

            }//while

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Do a discovery and see if it shows up in the results (i.e. do you get an ACTION_FOUND for it).  I think this is a bad idea because it is very resource intensive in that the Bluetooth radio can't really do anything else and it consumes a lot of spectrum since it has to broadcast on all channels.
2. Try to connect to it, e.g. do a socket connect to a known UUID.  If the device is no longer around the connect will fail in about 5 seconds (which is about a third what it takes to complete a discovery).  If the device is around, and you were recently connected to it (so your Bluetooth radio knows knows its clock offset) then you will connect to it quite quickly.

For implementing #2, this is the method I had in mind:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#connect%28%29)

And here is some code for using it:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient

Comment: thanks Tom, I like  your second method but I don't know how to use it in code. can you take one example so that it will be more clear to me. thanks again.

Comment: but how to get UUID of the device.